# Use two branches in Jenkins with git

Tags: git, jenkins

How I set a job in Jenkins in order to checkout two branches, change differents files in both, and push the changed files back to remote repository using git?

I tried to use the GitPublisher (a component of Git plugin) to push the modified files on each branch, but the plugin pushes the current HEAD equally to both branches as specified in the documentation, so the two branches will have the same commits and files. I don't want this situation because the two branches have different files that should be pushed separately

PS: I know I can use git commands in the shell and do it manually, but I would avoid insertion of commands with data like user name and password

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is a possibility of injecting passwords as environment variables - including some protection of the passwords. Would that help?

Comment: Yes, this solution will help me in a shell commands approach. Thank you